# How do I compile this project from github?

Tags: c#, github, building

https://github.com/bladecoding/LoLNotes

Does anyone know how I get that to run? I'm pretty sure I need to compile it with something but I just don't know what or how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written in C#, You can compile it using Visual Studio version that would allow You to compile against .NET frameworks 3.5 and 4.0.

Visual Studio 2010 or newer will be enough.

You can download free Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/E/72E0F986-D247-4289-B9DC-C4FB07374894/wdexpress_full.exe)

**update**:
Managed to build it. First I removed pre-build event from LoLNotes project properties as this is the one that calls gitExport.exe (I'm pretty sure You don't need it). Then I needed to re-add some certificate file to LoLNotes project as it couldn't find it even though it was there. After that solution builds successfuly.

Comment: Dunno why but that crashes as soon as I try to run it.

Comment: What crashes? Visual Studio, compiled application or what?

Comment: VS crashes, I got 2010 to work but it gives me this error http://puu.sh/acsxC/07e76b344d.png

Comment: I can't promise, but I'll try to look into this if I find some time tomorrow.

Comment: So I remove the pre-build event from here: http://puu.sh/adNrf/b902c728d7.png correct? How exactly do I add the certificate files? I've got no experience with this.

Comment: You right click LoLNotes project in solution explorer, then properties -> build events and just clear the text in pre-build event. Then if You got an error about missing file You go in solution explorer to that file, right click and unload from project, then right click on the folder and "Add existing item".

Comment: Works fine now, but how do I compile it to a standalone .exe?

Comment: After the build succeeds all binaries that are made by this solution should be in  /bin/debug or /bin/release folder in LoLNotes project folder.